# On data binding: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview, linq-to-entities

I'm using `LINQ to Entities`

My GridView is the following :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True"
    EmptyDataText="No Data" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="1"
    AllowSorting="True" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit"
    OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" CssClass="gridview"
    OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting" HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F0F0F0" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="SoftwareName" SortExpression="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Key" DataField="Key" SortExpression="Key" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" DataField="Date" ItemStyle-CssClass="date_td" SortExpression="Date"
            ReadOnly="True">
            <ItemStyle CssClass="date_td"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ToolTip="edit" ID="EditButton" CommandName="Edit"
                    ImageUrl="~/images/edit.png" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="UpdateButton" ToolTip="Submit" CommandName="Update"
                    ImageUrl="~/images/ok.gif" />
                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="Cancel" ToolTip="Submit" CommandName="Cancel"
                    ImageUrl="~/images/cancel.gif" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ToolTip="Delete" ID="btnDelete" CommandName="cDelete"
                    ImageUrl="~/images/delete.png" OnCommand="OnDelete" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("id") %>'
                    OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure ?')" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" />
</asp:GridView>
```

I fill the GridView with the following c# code :

```
private IQueryable SortGridView()
{
    IQueryable<Softwares> softwares = Search();

    if (softwares == null) return null;

    string sortExpression = (ViewState["SortExpression"] as string) == null
                                ? "ID"
                                : ViewState["SortExpression"] as string;
    string lastDirection = (ViewState["SortDirection"] as string) == null
                                ? "ASC"
                                : ViewState["SortDirection"] as string;

    switch (sortExpression)
    {
        case "ID":
            softwares = (lastDirection == "ASC")
                                ? softwares.OrderBy(q => q.id)
                                : softwares.OrderByDescending(q => q.id);
            break;

        case "Name":
            softwares = lastDirection == "ASC"
                            ? softwares.OrderBy(q => q.softwareName)
                            : softwares.OrderByDescending(q => q.softwareName);
            break;

        case "Key":
            softwares = (lastDirection == "ASC")
                            ? softwares.OrderBy(q => q.Keys.Key)
                            : softwares.OrderByDescending(q => q.Keys.Key);
            break;

        case "Date":
            softwares = lastDirection == "ASC"
                            ? softwares.OrderBy(q => q.Date)
                            : softwares.OrderByDescending(q => q.Date);
            break;
    }

    return from q in softwares
            select new
                        {
                            ID = q.id,
                            SoftwareName = q.softwareName,
                            Key = q.Keys.Key
                            Date = q.Date.ToString()
                        };
}

protected void ButtonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = SortGridView();
    GridView1.DataBind();// <<--- Exception
}
```

But in `ButtonSearch_Click` I get the following exception :

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

I've done it before with the LINQ to SQL without any problems, what is wrong with it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ to Entities queries are internally converted into sql statements. In your case its just that, LINQ to Entity provider is not able to map the "toString" call into a suitable SQL statement. You can retrieve the data from LINQ to entity and then enumerate offline and make the necessary changes i.e. :

```
var data = (from q in softwares
            select new
                        {
                            ID = q.id,
                            SoftwareName = q.softwareName,
                            Key = q.Keys.Key
                            Date = q.Date
                        }).ToList();
```

and then convert the Date part by calling ToString() method offline.

```
data.ForEach(item => item.Date = item.Date.ToString());
```

You are returning anonymous type from your method. Anonymous types are accessible only within the class where they are defined. You can try something like the code I have given below :

```
private IList<SoftwareInfo> SortGridView()
{
    // regular code

    return (from q in softwares
            select new SoftwareInfo
                        {
                            ID = q.id,
                            SoftwareName = q.softwareName,
                            Key = q.Keys.Key,
                            Date = q.Date
                        }).ToList();
}


public class SoftwareInfo
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string SoftwareName {get;set;}
    public string  Key {get;set;}
    public DateTime Date {get;set;}
}

protected void ButtonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = SortGridView();
    GridView1.DataBind();// <<--- Exception
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But in `ForEach` line , when I wanna assign item.Date.ToString to item.Data, this error has occurred : `Property or indexer 'AnonymousType#1.Date' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only`

Comment: Also, there is another error : `Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime'`

Comment: Well I see the problem. You are returning an anonymous type from "SortGridView" method. Anonymous type scope is only limited within the class where they are defined. You can solve this issue either by using "dynamic"  functionality of C# or by defining a concrete class.

Comment: What exception you are getting?

Comment: the same exception on `GridView1.DataSource = SortGridView();` line