# Convert field in linq query c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a query and i want to convert a decimal field to string but the query return the above error

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString () "and it can not be translated into term store.
```

My query :

```
    var t = (from f in db.teacher_fee
             where f.fee_status == 1
             select new
             {
                 f.fee_date,
                 f.teacher_fee_id,
                 debit = "",
                 credit = f.total_amount.ToString()
             });
```

can someone help me 
thanks

Comment: it not my case !!

Comment: You can find an answer to your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8192329/1694711

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466166.aspx

Comment: try `credit = SqlFunctions.StringConvert(f.total_amount)`  namespace is System.Data.Objects.SqlClient

Comment: @ElHamza - I'm sorry but it is... The `ToString` is used in the `select` on a value from the iterated item - Just like in your case

Comment: thank you all I'll show what I can do

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply methods like (System.ToString() in your example) on something that is not on the memory.

So basically, the query was never executed. If you look at it, this is still a IQueryable.

You need to bring it with AsEnumerable() or ToList(), before applying the methods into your fields.

Comment: thank you I see now